LevelDB heavy I/O writes and reads in Sync Data folder of Edge and Workspaces
I don't understand what is happening to Edge browser with Workspaces feature. There are heavy I/O writes and reads of .ldb files in User Data\Profile\Sync Data\LevelDB. When there are 2000-3000 I/O delta writes Edge freezes. It can take hours. In few hours there are several hundreds of GBs writes to disk.
I have plenty of PC power (12-core Ryzen 3900X, 32GB RAM, Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB). Edge unfreezes when writes drop. I can force less writes by turning off Internet or by blocking IPs that are connecting with Edge (it will stop sync). When I close Workspaces and load same tabs everything is fine. I think that they used Chromium LevelDB folder used to sync settings, favourites, history and they abuse it by putting too much data and refreshing too often and LevelDB can't make it and freezes Edge. Maybe values in tables are too long because I saw favicons there?
I wonder what is happening there and what I can do to make it not freezing the browser. Of course there is no support from Microsoft. Can someone explain and maybe tell what I can do to make it less writes or faster? Should I setup ramdisk for Sync Data?
.ldb files
I/O writes delta
2024/06/28-20:24:00.154 af28 Compacting 4@0 + 2@1 files
2024/06/28-20:24:00.186 af28 Generated table #792402@0: 18403 keys, 2109328 bytes
2024/06/28-20:24:00.205 af28 Generated table #792403@0: 46458 keys, 851893 bytes
2024/06/28-20:24:00.205 af28 Compacted 4@0 + 2@1 files => 2961221 bytes
2024/06/28-20:24:00.206 af28 compacted to: files[ 0 5 9 0 0 0 0 ]
2024/06/28-20:24:00.206 af28 Delete type=2 #792392
2024/06/28-20:24:00.206 af28 Delete type=2 #792393
2024/06/28-20:24:00.206 af28 Delete type=2 #792395
2024/06/28-20:24:00.206 af28 Delete type=2 #792397
2024/06/28-20:24:00.207 af28 Delete type=2 #792399
2024/06/28-20:24:00.207 af28 Delete type=2 #792401
2024/06/28-20:24:00.544 af28 Level-0 table #792405: started
2024/06/28-20:24:00.555 af28 Level-0 table #792405: 1495552 bytes OK
2024/06/28-20:24:00.557 af28 Delete type=0 #792400
2024/06/28-20:24:00.952 af28 Level-0 table #792407: started
2024/06/28-20:24:00.964 af28 Level-0 table #792407: 1495927 bytes OK
2024/06/28-20:24:00.965 af28 Delete type=0 #792404
2024/06/28-20:24:01.357 af28 Level-0 table #792409: started
2024/06/28-20:24:01.368 af28 Level-0 table #792409: 1496087 bytes OK
2024/06/28-20:24:01.370 af28 Delete type=0 #792406
2024/06/28-20:24:01.758 af28 Level-0 table #792411: started
2024/06/28-20:24:01.769 af28 Level-0 table #792411: 1496373 bytes OK
2024/06/28-20:24:01.771 af28 Delete type=0 #792408

I wrote on Microsoft forum, sent many bug reports and was checking Process Hacker. I used versions Stable, Beta, Dev, Canary. I tried different profiles. I tried blocking IPs connecting to Edge to check if it's not external impact (it only turns off or on sync).

I can give you the following suggestions for your reference:

You can navigate to "Control Panel>Programs>Programs and Features" to find Edge and repair it.
You can also create a new profile in Edge or directly delete the User Data folder to see if this problem can be solved.
As you described, turning off synchronization will force write reduction. So, you can use the "SyncDisabled" policy to force synchronization off. You can refer to this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-policies#syncdisabled
Of course, since the Edge Workspace feature has just been launched, you can submit feedback on the problems you encounter by clicking the Like or Dislike button at the bottom of the Edge Workspace menu.

